# Prefer wired over wireless for local subnet using NetworkManager

Tags: wifi, routing, networkmanager, ethernet, metric

My wireless network is bridged to my wired network, so both have the same subnet. How do I tell NetworkManager to give the local subnet route on the wireless interface a higher metric than the route on the wired interface? There used to be a `route-metric` option (see [here](http://blog.felipe.lessa.nom.br/?p=129)), but this does not seem to be supported on my system, I get an `invalid property 'route-metric'` when trying to modify my connection using `nmcli`.

Note: I'm not talking about the default route here, that seems to work properly 'out of the box': that one *does* use the wired interface.

Comment: I dont' use gui's however read `man route` and search for the word `metric`, I think it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Doing it manually is no problem. But, I want it to be done automatically each time I connect to my wired network :)

Comment: See also [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/501406/make-networkmanager-prefer-ethernet-over-wifi-if-both-present "Make NetworkManager prefer ethernet over wifi if both present") whose answer is applicable to Debian/Ubuntu-based users.  That answer also notes that there is now a metric field in the NetworkManager GUI, so I assume `nmcli` also now allows it.